# Как в С возвратить массив из функции?

Tags: c

Есть функция, которая банально проверяет являеться ли число бинарным

```
char* bool_input(void){
  char u_inpt[10]="";
  char result[10]="0";
  scanf("%s",u_inpt);

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(u_inpt); i++) {
    char num = *(u_inpt+i);

    if (num!=*("1")&&num!=*("0")) {
      printf("Error\n");
      bool_input();

    }
    // strcpy(u_inpt, result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

но она не работает так как возвращаемый объект не char* как вернуть ? P.S искренне прошу прощение если вопрос детский на с я сегодня начал писать

Comment: Можно так: return (char*) result; Но в си не приветствуется возврат массива из функции в виде указателя, будьте осторожны

Comment: `result` - локальный массив, он перестает существовать при выходе из функции.

Comment: `num!=*("1")&&num!=*("0")` - это какой-то сюр.

Comment: `num != '1' && num != '0'`, и все...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё дело в том, как вы создаете `result`.

В языке си при вызове функции в стеке (вызовов) выделяется память под локальные переменные, то есть аргументы и переменные указанные в начале функции. При этом, например, `char arr[100]` выделит 100 байт, `char * arr = malloc (100)` выделит только `sizeof (char *)` байт (то есть размер указателя).
При этом при выходе из функции все такие объекты уничтожаются. Не уничтожаются те объекты, память под которые была выделена в куче (например, функцией `malloc`).

Стало быть, Вам стоит выделять память под result с помощью команды `malloc` (из `stdlib.h`) и не забыть потом её освободить с помощью функции `free` в том месте, где `result` Вам более не нужен. Например:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char * f (void) {    
    char * result = malloc (n);
    // Проверка
    if (result == NULL) { return NULL; }
    // ...
    return result;
}

int main (void) {
    char * result;
    // ...
    result = f ();
    // ...
    free (result);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это один из способов. Второй способ: передавать в метод указатель на уже выделенный массив. Третий способ: статический массив. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11656532/5045688

Answer (score 4):

Если на минутку исключить из рассмотрения трюк с заворачиванием массива в `struct`, то в языке С невозможно буквально вернуть массив из функции (или передать массив в функцию). Массивы в С являются некопируемыми объектами - их нельзя никуда "передать" и ниоткуда "вернуть". Передавать или возвращать вы можете только *указатели* на массивы (на сами массивы или на их элементы).

По этой причине когда говорят о "возвращении массива из функции" в контексте языка С обычно понимают следующие варианты:

1. Возвращение указателя на массив (на начало массива). Возвращаемый указатель не может указывать на автоматический массив, объявленный внутри этой функции, так как такой массив будет уничтожен при выходе из функции.

   - Возвращаемый указатель может указывать на динамически выделенную память

     ```
     char *bool_input(void)
     {
       char *result = malloc(/* размер */);

       /* Заполнение массива */

       return result;
     }
     ```

     В таком случае освобождение выделенной памяти - обязанность вызывающего кода.
   - Либо он может указывать на массив со статическим временем жизни

     ```
     char *bool_input(void)
     {
       static char result[/* размер */];

       /* Заполнение массива */

       return result;
     }
     ```

     Большим недостатком такого варианта является то, что он нереентерабелен, но и у него (в различных вариациях) есть свои применения.
2. Массив передается в функцию снаружи и о его создании и удалении заботится именно вызывающий код. А функция занимается лишь заполнением массива

   ```
   void bool_input(char result[], size_t size)
   {
     /* Заполнение массива */
   }
   ```

   Если вам так больше нравится, вы можете сделать и так

   ```
   char *bool_input(char result[], size_t size)
   {
     /* Заполнение массива */

     return result;
   }
   ```
3. Ну и в качестве побочного варианта можно вспомнить об упоминавшемся выше варианте с заворачиванием массива в структуру. Такой вариант применяется редко и как правило имеет смысл лишь для массивов небольшого размера, которые всегда используются целиком

   ```
   struct Point
   {
     int xyz[3];
   }; 

   struct Point point_123(void)
   {
     return (struct Point) { { 1, 2, 3 } };
   }
   ```

Основным вариантом "возвращения массивов" в языке С является именно вариант номер 2. А вариант 1 при желании можно реализовать в виде надстройки над вариантом 2.